# onload hidding a region with modalform

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using the modalform width jquery, but i'm having one problem.

When the page is loading the modalform should be hidden and i wouldn't even see it, but in mine when loading it is showed and only after loading the page it hides.

And i have tried to use dynamic actions but it stills the same.

Anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the form is visible by default, and being hidden by Javascript after the page has loaded.  Perhaps you could change the template for the form region to include a surrounding `div` like:

```
<div style="display:none">
...
</div>
```

(Preferably, use a class rather than a style and put the specifics in CSS).

Comment: yes that was the problem i was using the id of the region, now i put it in a div like you said and add an id to it and is working fine. Tanks  :D